# Node image upload works well on local but returns 408 timeout error on aws-ec2

Tags: node.js, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, hapi

Image upload from react to s3 throgh hapi.js works perfectly on localhost but failes on aws ec2 with status code 408 (timeout).

I've tried with disabling aws timeout and increasing api timeout. It works for small size images but not for images having size more than about 5mb

React Code -

```
data.append('file', imagesToUpload[0]);
await axios.post('/hall/images', data, {
  headers: {
   'content-type': 'multipart/form-data'
   }
})
```

Hapi api code -

```
const uploadImages = {
  payload: {
      allow: 'multipart/form-data',
      maxBytes: 1048576*120
  },
  validate: {
    payload: {
      file: joi.any().required(),
    },
  },
  handler: async (req, h) => {
    const {file} = req.payload;
    const options = {queueSize: 1};
    const params = {
      ACL: 'public-read',
      Body: file,
      ContentType: 'multipart/form-data',
      Bucket: `***`,
      Key: Date.now().toString()
    };
    return s3.upload(params, options).promise();
}
```

Comment: Is port 443 open through the vpc to S3?

Comment: Yes 443 port is open

Answer (score 1):

If smaller size images upload fine then your ports and security groups are likely fine. If it's failing on larger images have you tried Multi Part uploads?

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/mpuoverview.html